# Почему в Docker postgresql база весит больше чем на сервере

Tags: postgresql, docker

У меня была база в Docker container которая которую я перенес на сервер, но после дампа я обнаружил что размер данных раличался на 2-10 мб. Только ни каких потерсь в данных не обнаружилось

Почему это могло случится

Я дампил данные из докера вот таким образом

```
sudo docker exec -i docker_container pg_dump -U username -d database > /home/plazun/dump.sql

sudo -u postgres -i

psql -d database < /home/plazun/dump.sql
```

---

В докере

```
                           List of relations
 Schema |      Name      | Type  |   Owner    |   Size   | Description
--------+----------------+-------+------------+----------+-------------
 public | table1         | table | owner      | 24 MB    |
 public | table2         | table | owner      | 127 MB   |
 public | table3         | table | owner      | 16 kB    |
 public | table4         | table | owner      | 10232 kB |
 public | table5         | table | owner      | 320 kB   |
(5 rows)
```

---

На сервере

```
                           List of relations
 Schema |      Name      | Type  |   Owner    |   Size   | Description
--------+----------------+-------+------------+----------+-------------
 public | table1         | table | owner      | 19 MB    |
 public | table2         | table | owner      | 71  MB   |
 public | table3         | table | owner      | 16 kB    |
 public | table4         | table | owner      | 10216 kB |
 public | table5         | table | owner      | 296 kB   |
(5 rows)
```

Comment: @Mike, по-моему, ваш комментарий вполне достоин того, чтобы стать ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При переносе БД она почти всегда уменьшается. Если с ней конечно шли какие то операции. Даже простое добавление записей в таблицу модифицирует индексы, они становятся не оптимальными по хранению, занимают больше места. А после полной перестройки они ложатся более оптимально.
При модификации/удалении строк postgresql оставляет старую копию и создает новую в другом месте таблицы. Место занимаемое старой записью через какое то время может быть использовано повторно, но это происходит не так уж и быстро, таблицы со временем начинают содержать большое количество пропусков. При дампе разумеется берутся только актуальные версии строк и пустого места в залитых с нуля таблицах нет.

Comment: Можно лишь еще добавить что если посчитанный БД размер своих таблиц зависит от файловой системы (а наверняка зависит, сложно предположить что база данных сама считает занятое место хранимых в ней данных), то та самая разница в файловых системах может играть роль. 

На самом деле можно провести эксперимент дополнительно - развернуть два дампа в докере, но в одном случае сделать volume с данными именованный, а в другом сделать его как bind, мне думается даже они будут различаться. Но это только теоретическое предположение.